# Apply function to array nodes until not array nodes are arrays

Tags: php

Let's say I have this structure, in an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Heading1
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => Heading2.1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => Heading2.2
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Heading1.2
        )

)
```

How do I go about applying a function only to the array elements holding heading2.1 and heading 2.2?

The function I want to apply may nest arrays even further. How can I make it so that my function will also run on these newly created arrays? And the arrays that are then created, until there are not arrays on the second deepest level?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through it recursively, check whether it's an array using the [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function and if so, apply your function.

Comment: Then for the second part of the question, how can I check if there are any array element on the second deepest level?

Answer (score 1):

A naïve recursion won't do, and re-running the recursion is a double no. What you want to use here is [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

> In computer science, a **topological sort** (sometimes abbreviated topsort or toposort) or topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that, for every edge *uv*, *u* comes before *v* in the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk() and test, in the function you will execute on each node, if the content is an array...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php